# sql where operator and in operator

Tags: sql, database, where-clause

I have the following code which works fine:

```
select 
     M.value1, P.value2 
from 
     table 1 P
join 
     table 2 E on (P.value2 = E.value2)
join 
     table 3 M on ( something else here)
where 
     P.value2 in (select value1 
                  from table 4
                  where (value 2 = “aaa”) and (value 3 = “bbb))
```

So here table 1 has column called value 2. I join it with table 2, which also has column called value 2 on the condition specified. I then join the result with table 3 based on some other condition. Then I add where operator  and in operator, which will return me some specific value1 values from table 4 based on condition specified. Thus some unwanted P.value2 values will be skipped.

Now my question is: if I have another table, say table 5, which has for instance columns called value1, value 2 and value 3 how do I sort P.value2 values further? I want to leave only P.value2 values, which correspond only to some criteria. I tried this code, but it didn’t work:

```
select 
    M.value1, P.value2 
from
    table 1 P 
join 
    table 2 E on (P.value2 = E.value2) 
join 
    table 3 M on ( something else here) 
where 
    P.value2 in (select value1 
                 from table 4 
                 where (value2 = “aaa”) and (value3 = “bbb))
    and P.value2 in (select value1 
                     from table 5 
                     where (P.value2 = value1) and (value3 = “ccc”))  
    or P.value2 in (select value2 
                    from table 5
                    where (P.value2 = value2) and (value3 = “ccc”))
```

Is this a correct way to use where operator and how could I optimize this? Once again, what I want to achieve is to add this bit:

> ```
> and P.value2 in (select value1 from table 5
> where (P.value2 = value1) and (value3 = “ccc”)) 
> or P.value2 in (select value2 from table 5
> where (P.value2 = value2) and (value3 = “ccc”))
> ```

to obtain desired P.value 2 values based on values from table 5. Thanks for any help!

So we have the joined table say:

```
value1 value2 value3 value1 value2 value1 value2
------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
bbbbb1 aaaaa1 ccccc1 ddddd1 aaaaa1 eeeee1 fffff1
bbbb24 aaaa24 cccc24 dddd24 aaaa24 eeee24 ffff24
bbbb32 aaaa32 cccc32 dddd32 aaaa32 eeee32 ffff32
bbbb42 aaaa42 cccc42 dddd42 aaaa42 eeee42 ffff42
..... etc
```

and we have the selected (sorted) table:

```
value1 value2
------ ------
eeeee1 aaaaa1
eeee24 aaaa24
eeee32 aaaa32
...etc
```

and now i want to sort this table further using table 5 which i:

```
value1 value2 value3
------ ------ ------
12223  aaaa12 ccc
12334  aaaa32 bbb
aaaa1  123344 ccc
12332  aaaa24 ccc
```

therefore here aaaa1 and aaaa24 should be left and aaaa32 should be removed from the final table.

Comment: Provide the schema and some data and expected output.

Comment: You could use OR: `WHERE (P.value2 = table5.value1 OR P.value2 = table5.value2)`

Comment: so how exactrly will this be? Sorry, please note that in line 3 of the last code block should be OR instead of AND. I edited it just now. Can I write something like this: and P.value2 in (select value1, value2 from table 5 ...) to avoid duplication? when I tried it, it threw me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
and P.value2 in (select value1 from table 5
where (P.value2 = value1) and (value3 = “ccc”)) 
or P.value2 in (select value2 from table 5
where (P.value2 = value2) and (value3 = “ccc”))
```

To

```
and P.value2 in (select value1 from table 5
where (P.value2 = value1 OR P.value2 = value2) and (value3 = “ccc”))
```